# Make User enter Input Strings in variables of my class through array.

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to learn various ways in which arrays can be used and i found an example in book which i tried to modify , my array is being made and i am able to create objects of reference variables in array object but i am not able to make user input values here is my code:

```
class Information {
     String author, title;
 }

public class Books {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Number of Books: ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
    Information myBooks[] = new Information[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        myBooks[i] = new Information();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        myBooks[j].author = bufferedReader.readLine();
        myBooks[j].title = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        System.out.println("author of " + myBooks[k].title + " is " + myBooks[k].author);
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

how can i make user input values in myBooks[0].author and myBooks[0].title and so on.

Comment: Maybe consider using `Scanner` instead? I've found that easier to work with user input, but that's just my opinion. http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @Michael i was just making a stupid mistake i corrected it apparently i tried your suggestion too and scanner and bufferedReader both work , Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

Geez i feel stupid :P But i got solution to my problem. 
code was working the way it was supposed to work, i just tried adding two sentences and it worked.. basically it was taking me into loop but i didnt know.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.println("Enter author's name for book "+ (j+1));
        myBooks[j].author = bufferedReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Title for book"+ (j+1));
        myBooks[j].title = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

so now when i enter the loop it asks to enter so i can enter :P